# How to restore time domain signal after multiply cosine signal when cosine signal has unknown initial phase?

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, time-frequency, time-series

I use [AD9954](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QLDXWZH) as cosine signal generator,then use [ad835](https://www.arduino-tech.com/ad835-multiplier-module-mixer-broadband-modem-4-quadrant-multiplier-dc-250mhz-frequency/) to multiply this cosine signal with antenna signal.
As [image],the antenna signal frequency shifted after `ad835`,then processed by SDR device.

[image]

When I read the SDR output IQ data,it's easy to know the frequency character.And,I plan to `IQ time domain data/cosine()` to restore the time domain data of `antenna signal`.

For the reason I cannot push the button of `ad9954` and `ad835` at the same time,I am not sure whether initial phase of `cosine` signal is `0`,which means I cannot guarantee `ad9954` generate cosine signal,maybe it generate sine signal.

In this situation,I am afraid `IQ time domain data/cosine()` cannot restore `antenna signal`.
How to restore time domain signal after multiply cosine signal when cosine signal has unknown initial phase?

Comment: Maybe multiply the signal by a cosine AND a sine signal ? It will make information extraction easier. Therefore, it should be easier to reconstruct the original signal from the extracted information.

Comment: @Ben,could you please write a simple answer.It's the first time I hear `information extraction`.